# NotePad sample in Android sdk: Where is a note stored?

Tags: android

If I build and then install a NotePad sample app on my handset, then write a note (and save it by backing out of the stack), where is that individual note stored in the file system?

Answer (score 0):

It is stored in a database, typically this database is stored in /data/< app's package name >/databases/

Answer (score 0):

It will be stored in a Database. read [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm) about SQLite database: